# swift command line tool for git commands, but its no

Tags: swift, git

I would like to create a tool for git commands using swift.

- I'm getting git error ***usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C ]
  [-c =]*.**
- Is there any way to distribute it as a command-line package and using in the *swift* file?

```swift
import Foundation

struct Task {
    static let shared = Task()

    func run(with args: String...){
        let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/git"
        task.arguments = ["-c", args.joined(separator: " ")]

        let pipe = Pipe()
        task.standardOutput = pipe
        task.launch()

        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
        print(output)
        task.waitUntilExit()
    }
}


let task = Task.shared
task.run(with: "status")
task.run(with: "fetch --all")
task.run(with: "add --all")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using deprecated methods in your code and there are some other things missing.

First we should set the shell to use

```
func run(with args: String...){
    let task = Process()
    task.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/zsh")
```

Then instead of using the deprecated `launchPath` we build a string with the full command and set it as the arguments for the task

```
let arguments = "/usr/bin/git \(args.joined(separator: " "))"
task.arguments = ["-c", arguments]
```

I also think it is a good idea to handle any errors by checking standard error

```
let pipe = Pipe()
let errorPipe = Pipe()
task.standardOutput = pipe
task.standardError = errorPipe
```

Instead of using the deprecated `launch` method use `run` and read both standard out and standard error

```
do {
    try task.run()

    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    if !data.isEmpty {
        if let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print(output)
        }
    }

    let error = errorPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    if !error.isEmpty {
        if let errorMessage = String(data: error, encoding: .utf8) {
            print(errorMessage)
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

For a simple command it might be worth having the handling of standard output and standard error in an `if/else` so feel free to change that but for more complicated commands dealing for example with multiple files it might produce both output and errors

Comment: thank you, got the issue, ur detailed comments are really helpful to understand the issue. Thanks again, have a fun day.