# macOS Swift Launch Location Not Accessible

Tags: swift, macos

I want to execute the following shell command from my macOS app:

```
/Users/macuser/Desktop/videos/ffmpeg -i /Users/macuser/Desktop/videos/vid1.mov -vf fps=1/1 /Users/macuser/Desktop/videos/images/out%0d4.jpg
```

The method I'm using to do this is:

```
func shell(_ launchPath: String, _ arguments: [String]) -> String?
{
    let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = launchPath
        task.arguments = arguments
       
        let pipe = Pipe()
        task.standardOutput = pipe
        task.standardError = pipe
        task.launch()
        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
        task.waitUntilExit()

    return output
}
```

I am passing the arguments to the method like this:

```
let command = ffmpegLocation
let arguments = [
    "-i",
    videoLocation,
    "-vf",
    "fps=1/1",
   "\(outputLocation)/out%0d4.jpg"
]
resultsField.stringValue = shell(command,arguments)!
```

What I get is "launch path is not accessible". I have verified the command does work in Terminal. Do I need to use a different approach?

Comment: launchPath is deprecated, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66580060/swift-command-line-tool-for-git-commands-but-its-no/66580905#66580905) for instance

Comment: Xcode is usually pretty good at showing when something is deprecated. It didn't this time. Thanks for the link! All is well!