# I want to create a mac app to run shell command

Tags: swift, macos, shell

I want to create a mac app to run shell command, but it only run the command in `/bin` directory, can't run the command such as `pod`. what's wrong with it? I try to edit `.bash_profile` but not work.
And the code is working in terminal app which build by SPM.

```swift
    let task = Process()
    let pipe = Pipe()
    
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.standardError = pipe
    task.arguments = ["-c", command]
    task.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "bin/sh")
```

Comment: Check [this](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/building-a-command-line-tool-using-the-swift-package-manager/) tutorial.

Comment: tks, but it isn't a mac app, it is a terminal app.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66580905/9223839) could be helpful

Comment: IIRC, The bash profile isn't loaded for non-interactive sessions, so you'll need to check what flags you need to pass to make it an interactive and/or login session